Iphone website bookmark download image issue
I have a website bookmark on my iPhone (Iphone 14) homescreen. This opens a website in full screen.
When I click on a download image link in the website it brings up an iPhone screen to choose 'Open in instagram' or 'more'
Once an option has been chosen to save the image, there is no way to close the 'download' screen. Does anyone know how to close the screen and return to the website.
When accessing and downloading a file through the browser it works fine, but not when accessed through a homepage bookmark.
